# Javascript promise conversion

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm having a hard time understanding how promises works. I've seen some examples and some of it makes sense. However, when I try to actually use it I get stuck. I have the following example:
(I'm using q and nodejs. getItem() returns a promise, but my function doesn't wait for it.)

```
function calculate(id, item) {
   var calcId = id ? id : getItem(item);
   if (!id && calcId) { calcId = calcId.Id; }

   if (calcId) {
      update(calcId);
   } else {
      insert(item);
   }
}
```

Based on the examples, I don't see how to do it without code duplication.

Comment: What do you mean, "doesn't wait for it"? How else would it access its `.Id`? Or is that a property of the promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises are resolved asynchronously, so you can't treat them as synchronous as in your example.  What you want to do is coerce the value is a Q promise if needed, then proceed from there, that way you have deterministic behavior and no code duplication.

I'm making some assumptions here about `update` and `insert` returning promises and returning them when needed so that calculate itself returns a promise.

```
function calculate( id, item ) {
    return Q( id || getItem(item) ).then(function( calcId ) {

        // Code seems weird to be, but it's based on the original example.
        // Might want to review this.
        if ( !id && calcId ) {
            calcId = calcId.Id;
        }

        return calcId ?
            update( calcId ) :
            insert( item );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don’t duplicate your `id` checks:

```
function calculate(id, item) {
    var calcId;

    if (id) {
        calcId = id;
    } else {
        calcId = getItem(item).Id;
    }

    if (calcId) {
        update(calcId);
    } else {
        insert(item);
    }
}
```

Now make `calcId` consistently a promise holding an `Id`:

```
function calculate(id, item) {
    var p;

    if (id) {
        p = Promise.resolve({ Id: id });
    } else {
        p = getItem(item);
    }

    return p.then(function (calcId) {
        if (calcId.Id) {
            return update(calcId.Id);
        } else {
            return insert(item);
        }
    });
}
```

Where, in the case of Q, `Promise.resolve` is `Q.resolve`, or just `Q`.

Bonus: as a generator!

```
function calculate(id, item) {
   var calcId = id ? id : yield getItem(item);
   if (!id && calcId) { calcId = calcId.Id; }

   if (calcId) {
      update(calcId);
   } else {
      insert(item);
   }
}
```

Comment: Since id is undefined and I need to retrieve the item (getItem()) how exactly is q.resolve helping? That code is never reached. getItem() is the one I have to wait for...

Comment: @user3582665: Sorry, I completely forgot the `then`.

Answer (score 0):

Several points :

- Promise-wrapped results need to be handled with a function specified as a parameter of a promise method (eg `.then(fn)`)
- `Q(x)` can be used to ensure that `x` is Promise-wrapped. The operation is transparent if `x` is already a promise - it won't be double wrapped
- you need safety in case both `id` and `item` are empty or missing
- you need further safety in case `calcId` is falsy and `item` was not provided
- `id` versus `calcId.Id` can be more elegantly catered for.

```js
function calculate(id, item) {
    if(!id && !item) {
        throw new Error("'calculate(): parameters empty or missing'");
    }
    return Q(id ? {Id:id} : getItem(item)).then(function(resultObj) {
        var calcId = resultObj.Id;
        if(calcId) {
            update(calcId);
        } else {
            if(item) {
                insert(item);
            } else {
                throw new Error("'calculate(): `calcId` is falsy and `item` is empty of missing'");
            }
        }
        return calcId; //in case you need to chain calculate(...).then(...)
        //(Alternatively, if update() and insert() return promises, then return them instead as per dherman's answer)
    });
}
```

Call as follows :

```
calculate(myId, myItem).then(function(calcId) {
    //(optional) anything else you wish to do with `calcId`
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```